# Stress Energy tensor for non-relativistic particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to write down the elements of [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for a point particle moving with non-relativistic velocity $v$.

I have written : $ T_{00} = mc\delta(\vec{r} -\vec{r}') $ and $ T_{0i} = mc\dot{r}_{i}\delta(\vec{r} -\vec{r}')$ where $i=1,2,3$ and I am thinking about $T_{ij}$.  Is it correct to think of them as  $ T_{ij} = m\dot{r}_{i}\dot{r}_{j}\delta(\vec{r} -\vec{r}') $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula for a relativistic collection of particles is
$$T^{\alpha\beta}(x)=\sum_n\frac{p_n^\alpha p_n^\beta}{E_n}\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_n(t))$$
In nonrelativistic physics we take $E_n=m_n$ and $p^\alpha=m(1,v^i)$. Thus for one particle we see
$$T^{ij}(x)=m v^i v^j\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}(t))$$
Which is what you had.